# Spatie Medialibrary Custom Custom Directory As Prefix

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, file-upload, laravel-medialibrary

I am using `spatie/laravel-medialibrary:8.0`.

When I uploaded file, it was saved in `storage/public` directory.

```
1/filename.file_extension, 2/filename.file_extension...
```

I think `1, 2...` are ids of files.

Is there any way to put different prefix directory according to user?

For example, I want to put like this.

```
public/storage/user_id/1/filename.file_extension,
```

I searched about it but couldn't find exact answer,

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Show us how you are storing the files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  

$post->addMediaFromRequest('image')->toMediaCollection();

I stored like this.

Comment: I think the way to go is under docs [Using a custom directory structure](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v8/advanced-usage/using-a-custom-directory-structure/#main). Take a look at this post "best answer" [Spatie MediaLibrary default storage depending on the model](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/spatie-medialibrary-default-storage-depending-on-the-model)

Comment: Great!, It worked well! Please post answer!

Comment: checkout his video https://youtu.be/PEhxmEu4Bow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to go it's under docs [Using a custom directory structure](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v8/advanced-usage/using-a-custom-directory-structure/#main).

To override the default folder structure, a class that conforms to the `PathGenerator`-interface can be specified as the `path_generator` in the config file.

For example, you can create a new class that extends that interface and return some path for your models

```
class CustomPathGenerator implements PathGenerator
{
    public function getPath(Media $media) : string
    {
        if ($media instanceof Post) {
            return 'user_id/' . $media->user_id . '/' . $media->id;
        }
        return $media->id;
    }

    public function getPathForConversions(Media $media) : string
    {
        return $this->getPath($media) . 'conversions/';
    }

    public function getPathForResponsiveImages(Media $media): string
    {
        return $this->getPath($media) . 'responsive/';
    }
}
```

Then update the config file and point to that class:

```
'path_generator' => CustomPathGenerator::class,
```

---

References:

[spatie/laravel-medialibrary](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary) Docs [Using a custom directory structure](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v8/advanced-usage/using-a-custom-directory-structure/#main).

Laracasts [Spatie MediaLibrary default storage depending on the model](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/spatie-medialibrary-default-storage-depending-on-the-model) "best answer".

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you take a look this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62028837/spatie-laravel-medialibrary-cant-retrieven-file-from-backblaze-storage-this-dr

Comment: When you say, "update the config file and point to that class", what config file are you referring to?

Comment: @TopAngler I don't remember well because it's been a while since the last time I used that library. But I was referring to the library's configuration file [/config/medialibrary.php](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/blob/03586bc6eb4e2b15cdea91c85e6adff9e91f37f9/config/medialibrary.php#L82). If you can't find it in your project's config directory, you probably didn't publish it, then try `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaLibraryServiceProvider" --tag="config"` .